# having problem with different dialogues of english movies

Tags: grammar

Can we use 3rd form of verb after subject? E.g: I seen it. Mostly I have seen this sentence in Hollywood movies like another example "I been with you"

Comment: What do you mean with "3rd form of verb"? Your numbering seems strange or unusual. You might want to clarify your question and ask it at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: No it's grammatically incorrect and should be "have been". However this usage is typical of some uneducated American speech and you might well hear it in a Western or some other film.

Comment: It is grammatically incorrect *in Standard English*. In said Western dialects it is *perfectly grammatical*. On a side note, *english* is a spin you put on a ball in snooker or bowling. You probably mean *English*, the language. These are two different words.